# Minion Math and ConTeXt

Tags: context

can anybody please share the correct way (or a link with some documentation about it) to use Minion Math font and ConTeXt.

Answer (score 4):

```
\setupfontfamily[serif][DejaVu Serif]
\setupfontfamily[math] [Minion Math]
\starttext
$y=\int_1^ 4 x^2 dx $
\stoptext
```

Comment: What about optical sizes and bold?  One might want to use `MinionMath-Capt.otf` for subscripts or `MinionMath-Bold.otf` for boldface.

Comment: Then one has to define that special fonts have to be used for different sizes.